# Use grep to match and erase a pattern in a large chunck of text

Tags: regex, grep

I have a very large text file which contains data similar to the following:

```
     but/CC as/IN 1/Z church/NP historian/NN/Fc 
     as/IN 1/Z "/Fe rupture/NN and/CC new/JJ beginning/NN century/NN ./Fp
    ======>match found: \#\#[a-z]+\/NN\#\#
    ======>match found: be\/V[A-Z]+(\s[.]{0,10})?\#\#
    ======>match found: \#\#\sof\/IN
```

I would like to use the (linux) terminal command *grep* to match and erase all the lines that start with:

======>match found:

and end with a newline character.

Thus, according to the previous example, I'd like to run grep and obtain the following output

> but/CC as/IN 1/Z church/NP historian/NN/Fc 
>            as/IN 1/Z "/Fe rupture/NN and/CC new/JJ beginning/NN century/NN ./Fp

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: grep -i  "^======>match found:[.]\\n" ./mybigfile.txt

Comment: Please go back and edit your question to show us what you tried, and then to explain what didn't work, and how exactly it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not an expert in regex and I couldn't find the regex that matched exactly the pattern I needed, therefore the output was always similar to the input file, that's why I didn't post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -E -v '^======>match found:.+$' file.txt
```

`-E` turns on extended regular expressions, and `-v` negates the output, i.e. prints all lines that don't match.

Answer (score 1):

Sed is your friend

```
sed -i '/^======>match found:/d' largefilename.txt
```

will delete all occurrences of lines starting with `======>match found:`

Note, the `-i` switch means that the `largefilename.txt` will be modified rather than printed to stdout, which should be more efficient than using grep.