# Use grep to match and erase a pattern and its previous line in a large chunck of text

Tags: regex, grep

I have a very large text file which contains data similar to the following:

```
he/PRP have/VBD obtain/VBN the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## against/IN the/DT monk/NNS of/IN the/DT

craft/NN ,/Fc he/PRP obtain/VBD the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## of/IN besancon/NP ;/Fx and/CC have/VBD it/PRP in/IN
======>match found: \#\#\sof\/IN

succeed/VBN to/TO the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## ./Fp

klutzy/NN little/JJ ##scene/NN## where/WRB 1/Z brave/JJ french/JJ man/NN refuse/VBZ to/TO sit/VB down/RP for/IN fear/NN of/IN be/VBG discover/VBN ./Fp
======>match found: \#\#\swhere\/WRB\s
```

I would like to use grep to match and erase all those lines that contain a line of "text" followed immediately after a new line character with **=====>match found:** , as in:

```
craft/NN ,/Fc he/PRP obtain/VBD the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## of/IN besancon/NP ;/Fx and/CC have/VBD it/PRP in/IN
======>match found: \#\#\sof\/IN
```

and end with a newline character.

Thus, according to the previous example, I'd like to run grep and obtain the following output

```
he/PRP have/VBD obtain/VBN the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## against/IN the/DT monk/NNS of/IN the/DT

succeed/VBN to/TO the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## ./Fp
```

I have already tried: `grep -E -v '^.+\n======>match found:.+$' file.txt`

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14482938/use-grep-to-match-and-erase-a-pattern-in-a-large-chunck-of-text) by appending the regex `.+*\n` to the command to include the previous line, but it is not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried pressing Enter instead of `\n`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove matching and previous line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566616/remove-matching-and-previous-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` command is close to what you want:

```
$ sed -n 'N;/\n======>match found:/d; P;D' textfile 
he/PRP have/VBD obtain/VBN the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## against/IN the/DT monk/NNS of/IN the/DT


succeed/VBN to/TO the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## ./Fp
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi-line grepping is complicated by the fact that traditional grep implementations only consider one line at a time, so adding `\n` to your pattern doesn't make sense.

If you have pcregrep available multi-line matching can be done with the `-M` flag:

```
pcregrep -Mv '^.+\n======>match found:.+$'
```

Output:

```
he/PRP have/VBD obtain/VBN the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## against/IN the/DT monk/NNS of/IN the/DT


succeed/VBN to/TO the/DT ##archbishopric/NN## ./Fp
```